# how to send an email alert if a folder is modified

Tags: email, inotify, mutt

I want to get an email alert if a certain folder is modified but how do I pipe the output from the command so it sends an email not just show the changes to the folder in the terminal?

something like the following but... gives an error on the email part

```
inotifywait -m /home/tom -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        | /usr/bin/Mail -s "notify" "email@12345mail.com"
    done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be you simply missed the semicolon before `done`?

This line works for me (note I also used `mutt` instead of `Mail`):

```
inotifywait -m /home/tom -e create -e moved_to | while read path action file; do echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'" | /usr/bin/mutt -s "notify" "email@12345.com" ;done
```